# amsmath alignment problem within array

Tags: tables, amsmath, arrays

I'm trying to typeset this messy handwritten solution:

[image]

I plan on putting the "checks" part of the solution in a 2 column table immediately under the (x,y) solution  -- i.e. 1 cell for each equation in the system.

But despite many changes to the `array` syntax, I can get the alignment quite right as you'll see when you compile.

One other problem in log file...I can't find the missing math special marker:
[image]

Your assistance is greatly appreciated as my students are eager to see this.

Thanks in advance!

mwe

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem,tasks}

\settasks{
%  after-item-skip=5em,
%  after-skip=2cm,
  label-width=2em,
  item-indent=3em,
  label=(\arabic*),
  column-sep=2em,
 }
\begin{document}

Solve each system of equations using the \textbf {substitution method}:

\begin{tasks}(2)
\task $\syslineskipcoeff{1}\systeme*{3x+y=-5, 11x+y=-21}$
\\
\\Rewrite 1st equation in terms of $y$
$\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{array}{rcrcrcr}
 3x & + & y & = & \multicolumn{3}{c}{-5} \\
-3x &   &    &   & -3x \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{r}{y} & = & -3x & -   5 \\[2.5ex]
%Substitute \[-3x-5\]
%for \[y\] in 2nd equation 
\multicolumn{3}{r}{11x&-&3x-5} & =  -21\\
     \multicolumn{3}{r}{8x-5} &=&-21\\[3ex]
8x&-&5&=-21
\\
&+5 &   &  +5 \\
\hline
&8x&=-16\\
&x&=-2
\end{array}$
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You cannot have `&` inside `\multicolumn`.

Comment: @egreg  thanks for the solution. How do I maintain alignment without the ampersands?

Comment: Why you need `multicolumn`? It seems that ones with ampersands are superfluous.

Comment: @Frank Mittelbach; Happy Birthday to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that employs the `\mathllap` and `\mathrlap` macros of the `mathtools` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathllap and \mathrlap macros
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{
%  after-item-skip=5em,
%  after-skip=2cm,
  label-width=2em,
  item-indent=3em,
  label=(\arabic*),
  column-sep=2em,
}
 
\begin{document}

Solve each system of equations using the \textbf{substitution method}:

\begin{tasks}(2)
\task $\syslineskipcoeff{1}\systeme*{3x+y=-5, 11x+y=-21}$

\medskip
Rewrite the first equation in terms of~$y$:

\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{array}{rCrCr}
 3x & + & y & = & -5 \\
-3x &   &   &   & -3x \\
\hline
    &   & y & = & -3x\mathrlap{{}- 5} \\[3ex]
%Substitute \[-3x-5\] for \[y\] in 2nd equation 
11x-3x & - & 5 & = & -21\\
    8x & - & 5 & = & -21\\[3ex]
    
    8x & - & 5 & = & -21\\
       & + & 5 &   &  +5\\
\hline
 & &\mathllap{8x} & = & -16\\
 & &           x  & = &  -2
\end{array}
\]
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Forgive me for sounding like one of my high school students, but your solution is sooo cool! Writing macros is light years away from my knowledge level. Many thanks for your assistance!